# Show that this is a subgroup of the permutation group ${\sf aut} (\Bbb N)$.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, permutations

Let ${\sf aut}(\mathbb N)$ be the group of all permutations of the positive integers $\mathbb N$. The set $$\mathcal G=\left\{g\in{\sf aut}(\mathbb N) : \lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\frac{|\{1\leq n\leq N : g(n)>N\}|}{N}=0\right\}$$ forms a subgroup of ${\sf aut}(\mathbb N)$. But I am unable to show it. My attempt is the following.

Take $f,g\in \mathcal G$. Then $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\frac{|\{1\leq n\leq N : f(n)>N\}|}{N}=0=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\frac{|\{1\leq n\leq N : g(n)>N\}|}{N}$.  I am guessing that $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\frac{|\{1\leq n\leq N : f(g(n))>N\}|}{N}=0$ but unable to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\{n\in[N]:fg(n)\notin[N]\}\subseteq \{n\in[N]:g(n)\notin[N]\}\cup g^{-1}\{n\in[N]:f(n)\notin [N]\}$

Comment: What do you mean by $[N]$?

Comment: Here I mean $[N]=\{1,2,\dots,N\}$, a common notation from finite set combinatorics.

Comment: How can I prove that if $f\in\mathcal G$, then $f^{-1}\in\mathcal G$?

Comment: If $k$ numbers in $[N]$ is mapped by $f$ to outside, then how many does $f^{-1}$?